# Android emulator consume too much CPU

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019 for mobile application development. I use Android Emulator for a long time but I have some issues with it only during the last month.

I have created some virtual device by Android Device Manager. The *hw.gpu.mode* property is set to **auto**. When I run this device in the emulator everything is running perfectly. Emulation is very fast and without problems. But when I click on the emulator close button and the device state is saved then everything freezes on a long time. My OS is not responding on any user input. After 5-10 minutes is emulator closed finaly.

Do you have some idea how to resolve emulator closing? I have no idea why emulator terminating takes so much time.

Comment: First of all, please create a new emulator, if this issue is still existed. If it is still existed, please open the `Android SDKs and Tools` check if you have some updates like this screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/GfX8V9Y  . Please make sure if you have install too much applications in this emulator, and close your emulator when you are debuging.

Comment: change used repository to google in android sdk manager and install Emulator version 30

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I tried both options today but not helped. And when I run the only emulator without debugging and then try to close it, everything freezes for 10 minutes.

Comment: have you tried the new emulator version? also post more information about your Hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So think that I found the right reason for my problems. I use a docking station connected to my laptop. When I connect my display to my laptop directly, all problems disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your answer, it will help others who have similar thread.